# Blazor page can't find reference to another page saved in Shared

Tags: dialog, blazor, mudblazor

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
    Error (active)  CS0246  The type or namespace name 'IntakeFormDialog' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I am not sure why it can't find a reference to my dialog box it's saved in Shared and I added a using to the page.

```
private async void ScheduleIntake()
    {
        if(selectedReferral == null){
            Snackbar.Add("No referral was selected. Please select a referral before attempting to schedule an intake", Severity.Warning);
        }else{
            var parameters = new DialogParameters() { ["ReferralId"]=selectedReferral.Id };
            Dialog.Show<IntakeFormDialog>("Schedule Intake", parameters);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Check if you are missing any `@using` or use full qualified name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
InatkeFormDialog
!=
ItakeFormDialog
```

Spelling mistakes are costly